# Parsing an HTML table using jsoup

Tags: java, performance, html, parsing

I am trying to parse HTML using "jsoup". This is my first time working with "jsoup" and I read some tutorials on it as well.

If you see my table, it has three `<tr>` as of now (I have shortened it down to have three table rows just for understanding purpose, but in general it will be more). Now I would like to extract `Cluster Name` from my table and its corresponding `host name`; so for example, I would extract `Titan` as cluster name and all its hostname whose status are down.

For `Titan` cluster name, I have two hostnames `machineA.abc.com` and `machineB.abc.com` in which `machineA` status is `up` but `machineB` status is `down`.

So, I will print out `Titan` as cluster name and print out `machineB.abc.com` as the hostname, since it is down.

I have two cluster names: one is `Titan` and the other is `Goldy`; so I want to find all the machines which are down for `Titan` cluster name only.

```html
<table border=1>
   <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Alert</td>
      <td>Cluster Name</td>
      <td>IP addr</td>
      <td>Host Name</td>
      <td>Type</td>
      <td>Status</td>
      <td>Free</td>
      <td>Version</td>
      <td>Restart Time</td>
      <td>UpTime(Days)</td>
      <td>Last probed</td>
      <td>Last up</td>
   </tr>
   <tr bgcolor="ffffff">
      <td><a href=showlog?ip_addr=127.0.0.1>Hist</a></td>
      <td><a href=http://127.0.0.1:8080/test?full=y>VI</a></td>
      <td bgcolor="ffffff">&nbsp</td>
      <td>Titan</td>
      <td>10.100.111.77</td>
      <td>machineA.abc.com</td>
      <td></td>
      <td bgcolor="ffffff">up</td>
      <td bgcolor="ffffff" align=right>88%</td>
      <td bgcolor="ffffff">2.0.5-SNAPSHOT</td>
      <td bgcolor="ffffff">2014-07-04 01:49:08,220</td>
      <td bgcolor="ffffff" align=right>381</td>
      <td>07-14 20:01:59</td>
      <td>07-14 20:01:59</td>
   </tr>
   <tr bgcolor="ffffff">
      <td><a href=showlog?ip_addr=127.0.0.1>Hist</a></td>
      <td><a href=http://127.0.0.1:8080/test?full=y>VI</a></td>
      <td bgcolor="ffffff">&nbsp</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>10.200.192.99</td>
      <td>machineB.abc.com</td>
      <td></td>
      <td bgcolor="ffffff">down</td>
      <td bgcolor="ffffff" align=right>85%</td>
      <td bgcolor="ffffff">2.0.5-SNAPSHOT</td>
      <td bgcolor="ffffff">2014-07-04 01:52:20,613</td>
      <td bgcolor="ffffff" align=right>103</td>
      <td>07-14 20:01:59</td>
      <td>07-14 20:01:59</td>
   </tr>
   <tr bgcolor="ffffff">
      <td><a href=showlog?ip_addr=127.0.0.1>Hist</a></td>
      <td><a href=http://127.0.0.1:8080/test?full=y>VI</a></td>
      <td bgcolor="ffffff">&nbsp</td>
      <td>Goldy</td>
      <td>10.100.111.77</td>
      <td>machineH.pqr.com</td>
      <td></td>
      <td bgcolor="ffffff">up</td>
      <td bgcolor="ffffff" align=right>88%</td>
      <td bgcolor="ffffff">2.0.5-SNAPSHOT</td>
      <td bgcolor="ffffff">2014-07-04 01:49:08,220</td>
      <td bgcolor="ffffff" align=right>381</td>
      <td>07-14 20:01:59</td>
      <td>07-14 20:01:59</td>
   </tr>       
</table>
```

I'd like to know if I can improve this slightly:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException, IOException {
    URL url = new URL("some_url");
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(url, 3000);

    ArrayList<String> downServers = new ArrayList<>();
    Element table = doc.select("table").get(0); //select the first table.
    Elements rows = table.select("tr");

    for (int i = 1; i < rows.size(); i++) { //first row is the col names so skip it.
        Element row = rows.get(i);
        Elements cols = row.select("td");

        if (cols.get(3).text().equals("Titan")) {
            if (cols.get(7).text().equals("down"))
                downServers.add(cols.get(5).text());

            do {
                if(i < rows.size() - 1)
                   i++;
                row = rows.get(i);
                cols = row.select("td");
                if (cols.get(7).text().equals("down") && cols.get(3).text().equals("")) {
                    downServers.add(cols.get(5).text());
                }
                if(i == rows.size() - 1)
                    break;
            }
            while (cols.get(3).text().equals(""));
            i--;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(downServers);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't need implementation specific features, declare variables using interface types. That is, instead of:

> ```
> ArrayList<String> downServers = new ArrayList<>();
> ```

Use the `List` interface:

```
List<String> downServers = new ArrayList<>();
```

---

You can remove the `JSONException` throws declaration from the `main`, as it will never happen.

---

Your main loop can be written a bit simpler, for example:

```
Iterator<Element> rowIterator = rows.iterator();
rowIterator.next();
boolean wasMatch = false;

while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
    Element row = rowIterator.next();
    Elements cols = row.select("td");
    String clusterName = cols.get(3).text();

    if (wasMatch && clusterName.isEmpty() || clusterName.equals("Titan")) {
        wasMatch = true;
        if (cols.get(7).text().equals("down")) {
            downServers.add(cols.get(5).text());
        }
    } else {
        wasMatch = false;
    }
}
```

---

I would also wrap a row in a class with convenient accessors like this:

```
class ServerInfo {
    final Elements cols;

    ServerRowWrapper(Elements cols) {
        this.cols = cols;
    }

    String getClusterName() {
        return cols.get(3).text();
    }

    String getServerName() {
        return cols.get(5).text();
    }

    boolean isDown() {
        return cols.get(7).text().equals("down");
    }
}
```

which will make the main loop much more intuitive and free from hardcoded numbers like 3, 5, 7:

```
while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
    ServerInfo serverInfo = new ServerInfo(rowIterator.next().select("td"));
    String clusterName = serverInfo.getClusterName();

    if (wasMatch && clusterName.isEmpty() || clusterName.equals("Titan")) {
        wasMatch = true;
        if (serverInfo.isDown()) {
            downServers.add(serverInfo.getServerName());
        }
    } else {
        wasMatch = false;
    }
}
```

---

Finally, to make future changes easier to test, add some unit tests.

As the first step, extract the middle part from your `main` method, to take a `Document` as parameter and return the list of servers that are down:

```
static List<String> findServersDown(Document document) {
    List<String> downServers = new ArrayList<>();
    // ... rest of the code from main
    return downServers;
}
```

Change the `main` method to use the new `findServersDown` method:

```
public static void mainx(String[] args) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL("some_url");
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(url, 3000);
    System.out.println(ServerInfoParser.findServersDown(doc));
}
```

Add a unit test (or more!), for example:

```
public class ServerInfoParserTest {
    @Test
    public void testSecondServerDown() throws IOException {
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(new File("src/test/resources/test-data/table1.html"), "utf-8");
        List<String> downServers = ServerInfoParser.findServersDown(doc);
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList("machineB.abc.com"), downServers);
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE** (in response to your comment)

Instead of hardcoding `Titan`, it's better to generalize. It's easy enough to do.

Pass in a set of names to `findServersDown` and adjust the `if` condition in the loop:

```
static List<String> findServersDown(Document document, Set<String> names) {
    // ...

    while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
        // ...

        if (wasMatch && clusterName.isEmpty() || names.contains(clusterName)) {
            // ...
```

Then in the unit test:

```
Set<String> names = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("Titan"));
List<String> downServers = ServerInfoParser.findServersDown(doc, names);
```

This way the method will return the list of server names in any of the clusters you specified.

If instead of a flat list of server names, if you want them grouped by the name of the cluster, that should be easy to do as well, just rework the return type to a `Map<String, Set<String>>` instead.